# Replace store address with custom text in invoice pdf

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, pdf

I want to replace my store address on invoice pdf with text "Tax Invoice/Bill of Supply/Cash Memo". I am trying to edit in Abstract.php where there is a method which inserts address on pdf : insertAddress(). But cannot understand what to change in the function.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did this myself, what I did is in my Abstract.php there is a function insertAddress() which inserts store address on pdf. I did this tweak in that fucntion:

```
$custom_text = "Tax Invoice/Bill of Supply/Cash Memo";
  foreach (explode("\n", $custom_text) as $value){
 //foreach (explode("\n", Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/identity/address', $store)) as $value){ Replacing address with invoice tax text
```

I think the above code is very much self explanatory. 
**PS:** Never edit the core files of magento instead make a controller and override the base files. I did this because it was too urgent and had no idea of overriding magento core files.